# How to resolve 'apparmor_parser: Unable to replace "docker-default"' error?

Tags: docker, apparmor

When i was setting up development kit for a project using docker, i received the below error when i executed the `docker-compose up -d` command

```
Starting cc-buildkit-docker_mysql_1   ... error
Starting cc-buildkit-docker_maildev_1 ... 

ERROR: for cc-buildkit-docker_mysql_1  Cannot start service mysql: AppArmor enabled on system but the docker-default profile could not be loaded: running `/sbin/apparmor_parser apparmor_parser -Kr /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-default736988292` failed with output: apparmor_parser: Unable to replace "docker-default".  Permission denied; attempted to load a profile while confined?

Starting cc-buildkit-docker_maildev_1 ... error
```

How should i resolve this ? Thanks in advance